# Traversing through data frame in R and retaining specific rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R. I have a data frame like follows:

```
df=data.frame(S_id=c("s13261","s13261","s13082","s13082","s2936","s2936","s2999","s2999","s2999","s2999","s2999"),T_id=c("A_3","BC_2","CT_5","G_32","HU_8","HU_9","Pk_4","Op_12","WQ_54","MN_23","NB_1"),Start=c(17947,18405,87,1220,2982,2982,13820,32320,38734,38741,44031),End=c(18363,19966,1259,3433,4597,4073,15014,33618,40603,40603,44339),Plus_minus=c("-","-","+","+","+","+","-","+","-","-","+"),status=c("5pp","3pp","3pp","5pp","5pp","5pp","5pp","5pp","3pp","3pp","5pp"))
```

I would like to traverse through data frame and group the row based on `S_id`. Later within the group I would like to compare every row within the group with its consecutive row and retain only rows where the difference between `Start` value of second row and `End` value of its previous row is less than 100 and has status either `5pp and 3pp` or `3pp and 5pp`. The output I expect is pasted below:

```
S_id   T_id   Start   End   Plus_minus  status
s13261  A_3  17947   18363        -      5pp
s13261  BC_2 18405   19966        -      3pp
s13082  CT_5  87     1259         +      3pp
s13082  G_32  1220   3433         +      5pp
```

Kindly guide me

Comment: @Jan Sorry for inconvenience, I have edited my question with real values. Kindly take a look.

Comment: The Plus_minus column still depends on sample$Start

Comment: @Jan I have re-editted. Sorry I over looked that column.

Comment: @RonakShah I have corrected the data frame. Kindly take a look.

Comment: can you list out your conditions for retaining the row more clearly? Why did you retain T_id A_3 ? The difference between start value of second row and end value of first row is not greater than 100?

Comment: @vagabond I would like to compare every pair of rows within the group and retain them if their difference between "Start" of second row and "End" of its previous row is less than 100. In my desired output, The difference between Start value of "BC_2" is "18405" and has status 3pp and its previous row has End value of A_3 is "18363" and has status "5pp". Their difference is less than 100 and hence they has to be retained. Similarly, "G_32" has start value as "1220" with status "3pp" and its previous row has 1259 as End value with status "5pp" and hence they are retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the wonderful `dplyr` package.

```
df %>%
group_by(S_id) %>%
mutate(diff = Start - lag(End), diff_status = lag(status))
```

The function `lag` accesses the element just **before** the actual element. Now, the only thing left to do is filter on the newly created column and decide whether or not you want to keep `NA` and negative values (ie overlapping):

```
df %>%
  group_by(S_id) %>%
  mutate(diff = Start - lag(End), diff_status = lag(status)) %>%
  filter(diff < 100 | is.na(diff), diff_status != status | is.na(diff_status)) %>%
  select(-diff,-diff_status)
```

Which yields for your example:

```
    S_id   T_id Start   End Plus_minus status
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>     <fctr> <fctr>
1 s13261    A_3 17947 18363          -    5pp
2 s13261   BC_2 18405 19966          -    3pp
3 s13082   CT_5    87  1259          +    3pp
4 s13082   G_32  1220  3433          +    5pp
5  s2936   HU_8  2982  4597          +    5pp
6  s2999   Pk_4 13820 15014          -    5pp
```

Comment: Thank you Jan. Alomost worked. But in group s2936, HU_8 and HU_9 has 5pp in their status and hence it has to be removed.

Comment: @Chudar: Updated, simply add another call to `lag()` on the status column.